# Displaying data in table without knowing number of columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on writing a web application in MVC in which I retrieve data from SQL.  I need to display this data on the page however, and this is the annoying part, I potentially won't know all of the columns being returned.

Normally I would have a class that would form part of my `Model` allowing me to specifically state what each column was and it would work fine.

I've had a look at dynamic tables but even they seem to need some kind of known quantity for the columns (I may be looking at the wrong thing).

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how I could go about this?  I've been pulling my hair out trying to think of how I can write this code but I'm utterly stuck.

-- 
**Edit**
One of the things the SQL dev and I have pondered is a secondary stored procedure which would return a list of the column headers, possibly with a true/false to state if they are to be used.  To me this seems very messy though.

Comment: How is your data represented? Custom `class`, `DataTable` or something else?

Comment: What you tried ? post your code.

Comment: @AjayPunekar there is no code.  As I said I have been struggling to think how to write this.  The code I have is for DB calls where I know what exactly is being returned, so that isn't much use in this scenario.

@Mathew that's open at the minute.  For other items I've used a custom class, but I've known what they are.  So at the minute it is just an SP call and what I do with the `SqlDataReader` after that is open to discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

When I get he data back from `SQL` I iterate through the list as expected

```
var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
List<string> columns = null;
if (schemaTable != null)
columns = schemaTable
.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.Select(r => (string) r["ColumnName"])
.ToList();
```

Whilst it isn't the best way, because I have to hide certain columns I then call a separate utility method to validate whether each column is to be used.  The list of what is to be displayed / hidden I have stored in a separate SQL table.

The utility method creates a custom column object containing the column header, value and whether it is visible.  This is then added as a list to the standard data that I know to display.

In my View I then iterate through my main list as normal, but for each row iterate through the list of custom columns, checking for whether it is visible, and creating each column based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have a loop for writing line to line dynamically. Now, you need another loop inside for writing columns. Database objects such as datareader and datatables generally have a property to count columns and iterate then. I can't provide coding examples because it will depend on database objects you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best way that I've been able to retrieve SQL tables without knowing  column names, order, etc.

The table 'expands' as you add more columns so you don't have to adjust for changes.

> It doesn't depend on DataTable is which bulky and slow.

**Requires at least: C# 4.0**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public static class Validation
{
    public static List<dynamic> GetTable()
    {
        string _sql = "Select * from MyTable"
        List<dynamic> table = null;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(HelperData._conn_string))
            {
                _conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, _conn))
                {
                    _cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        table = new List<dynamic>();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var row = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

                            for (int field = 0; field <= reader.FieldCount - 1; field++)
                            {
                                row.Add(reader.GetName(field), reader[field]);
                            }
                            table.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        return table;
    }
}
```